# How to merge/join two components Parent/Child state react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

A newbie plight to how to handle/merge state. I have an inventory UI I'm trying to create, what I want to achieve is this, every time a new item gets added to ItemVariation, it appends to the Item component. I'm using a Django backend not that it matters but I want to add ItemVaration as a reverse relation to Item Table.

something like this.
`state = [{Item},[{ItemVariation}, {ItemVariation}]]`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ItemVariation from './ItemVariation';


export const Item = (props) => {
    const fetchCategory = 'http://localhost:8000/api/product/categories/'
    const fetchManufacturer = 'http://localhost:8000/api/product/manufacturers/'
    const fetchBranch = 'http://localhost:8000/api/users/branch/'


    const [manufacturer, setManufacturer] = useState([])
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
    const [branch, setBranch] = useState([])
    const [item, setItem] = useState({
                                        name: '',
                                        category: categories,
                                        branch: branch,
                                        manufacturer: manufacturer,
                                        has_size: false,
                                    })
    useEffect(() => {
        const cat = axios.get(fetchCategory);
        const man = axios.get(fetchManufacturer);
        const bra = axios.get(fetchBranch);
        
        axios.all([cat, man, bra]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
            setCategories(responses[0].data)
            setManufacturer(responses[1].data)
            setBranch(responses[2].data)
            // use/access the results 
          })).catch(errors => {
            // react on errors.
            console.log(errors)
          })
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="category">Categories: </label>
                <select name="category" id="category" >
                    {categories.map((category, index)=>(
                        <option key={index} value={category.id}>{category.name}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label htmlFor="category">Manufacturer: </label>
                <select name="category" id="category" >
                    {manufacturer.map((man, index)=>(
                        <option key={index} value={man.id}>{man.name}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
            <label htmlFor="category">Branch: </label>
                <select name="branch" id="branch" >
                    {branch.map((bra, index)=>(
                        <option key={index} value={bra.id}>{bra.name}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="has_size">Has Size: </label>
                    <input type="radio" id="has_size" name="has_size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            {JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)}
            <ItemVariation />
        </div>




 import React, { useState } from 'react'


function ItemVariation(props) {
      const fields = {
            default_product_variation: '',
            color: '',
            price: '',
            quantity: '',
            model_number: '',
            sku: '',
            barcode: '',
            product_condition: '',
            size: '',
            extra_information: ''
      }
      const [variations, setVariations] = useState([fields])

      const handleAddItem = () => {
            setVariations([...variations, fields])
      }
      return (
            <div>
                  {variations.map((variation, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="default_product_variation">Make default: </label>
                                    <input type="radio" id="default_product_variation" name="default_product_variation" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="color">Color: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="color" name="color" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="price">Price: </label>
                                    <input type="number" id="price" name="price" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="wholesale_price">Wholesale Price: </label>
                                    <input type="number" id="wholesale_price" name="wholesale_price" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="quantity">Quantity: </label>
                                    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="model_number">Model Number: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="model_number" name="model_number" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="sku">SKU: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="sku" name="sku" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="barcode">Barcode: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <div>
                                          <label htmlFor="product_condition">Condition: </label>
                                          <select name="product_condition" id="product_condition">
                                                <option value="1">New</option>
                                                <option value="2">Refurbished</option>
                                                <option value="3">Repurposed</option>
                                          </select>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="size">Size: </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="size" name="size" />
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="extra_information">Extra Information: </label>
                                    <textarea id="extra_information" name="extra_information"></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <hr />
                        </div>
                  ))}
                  <button type="button" onClick={handleAddItem}>Add Another Item</button>
                 {JSON.stringify(variations, null, 2)}
            </div>
      )
}
export default ItemVariation
```

How do I approach this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have an attribute `variations` into your main item? Is there any constraint preventing you to do so?

Comment: I'm trying to make each component less bulky? I read somewhere that each components shouldn't do too much.